# Commit while database is BUSY

Tags: python, c++, database, sqlite, concurrency

I have two scripts, one in python and one in C++, reading and writing from the same table in SQLite.

I have two questions about how to handle concurrency:

1. During writing, if the table is currently BUSY (something else it's writing), `sqlite_exec()` in C++ returns an Error code (5). It looks like in python this is not available, so I am wondering: what does it happen when python `commit()` while an other script is writing? In C++ it would just go on with its operation. Is there a way to know that commit() did not work as expected?
2. My (really inefficient) workaround in C++ is to keep checking the results of `sqlite_exec()`, and if it returns 5 (BUSY) I write again. Is there a more efficient way to do this, that avoids checking for the result in a loop until UPDATE returns the correct result?

Comment: If you need multiple processes writing to the db at once, sqlite is the wrong tool.

Comment: I actually only have two scripts accessing the same table, and I want I to be according to a sequential structure. C++ computes something and updates a table, then python gets those results, computes something else and updates the table. This goes on for multiple iterations.

Comment: Two counts as multiple.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant a significant amount. I chose SQLite because of its simplicity, since my focus is on the ML implementation. Off-topic, but really helpful: do you have suggestions on a very simple tool to process that? (MySQL?)

Comment: As long as multiple connections don't try to write to the database at the same time, it's fine. (Normally if one connection is writing, none can be reading at the same time; use WAL mode if you want to allow readers at the same time as a writer)

Comment: Also [sqlite3_busy_timeout()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html) is useful in C or C++.